# Jenkins job management conventions

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have been using Jenkins for some time now and it is working fine. Now I have a few questions regarding the convention I should use. Currently:

- I am unpacking the source codes in the `workspace/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/code` and  and building them in the `workspace/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/build`
- I am unpacking the build verification tests (BVT) in the `workspace/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/bvt`
- I am saving my JUnit test results in the `workspace/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/test-results` and Jenkins is reading from this directory and publishing the JUnit test result reports.

Or I should use the jobs directory i.e.

```
jobs/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/code
jobs/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/build
jobs/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/bvt
jobs/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/test-results
```

Or I should do all this inside the

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<JOB_NAME>/builds/<BUILD_NUMBER>
```

Can anyone please suggest what is the standard practice and convention?

Comment: I think this is question best answered by the build tool you choose to use. For example Maven comes with it's own directory conventions. You have tagged this question as Eclipse, but it is more normal to build the code using tools like ANT, Maven or Gradle

Answer (score 0):

The only real convention is not to use anything explicit like `workspace/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/code`, and certainly not `jobs/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/code`. Jenkins runs all commands in the current build's workspace, so you should just use the current working directory in (almost) all cases.

Beyond that, use your build environment's preferred convention. If your tool doesn't have one, then consider adopting a convention from a well-known tool. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) probably has the most complete set of conventions, or at least the best documentation for the convention.